# single insert ignore on a table with no auto-increment

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking, insert, blocking

For this table, in mysql 5.7,

```
    CREATE TABLE `t` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `val` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

- The table doesn't have autoincrement column
- The table doesn't have partitions
- There **ONLY** queries that are performed on this table are **INSERT** and **SELECT**
- the table is not used in any subqueries
- sql_mode doesnt have any STRICT_* enabled

I need to insert into this table, but the `id` value exists in >50% of the cases.
I want to use a single INSERT IGNORE instead of "SELECT id" , if doesnt exist "INSERT"

When doing an INSERT IGNORE, **(NOT a multi-insert one)**, and the **PRIMARY KEY** exists,
is/can there ANY locking involved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be confirmed in a test. Open two windows.

In the first window:

```
mysql> insert into t values (1, 10), (3, 30);
mysql> begin;
mysql> insert ignore into t values (1, 10);
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1062 | Duplicate entry '1' for key 't.PRIMARY' |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
```

The transaction is still uncommitted, so if we have locked the row, this transaction still holds the lock.

Now in the second window:

```
mysql> update t set val = val * 2 where id = 1;
<hangs waiting for lock>
```

Evidently the INSERT IGNORE in the first window did acquire a lock.

Comment: Interesting!  What exactly gets locked ?  show engine innodb lists the update as "trx id 11800(first window) lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting"

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html: _"If a duplicate-key error occurs, a shared lock on the duplicate index record is set."_ However, the status you observed seems to say it's an exclusive lock, not a shared lock.